# Getting Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access error while running wordcount on dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running the dataflow quickstart of wordcount module in apache beam package using python. I was able to run it locally on my machine . But, when I try to run it on dataflow service by specifying dataflow runner in the runner field, it is throwing error as :

```
 raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(http_response)
RuntimeError: apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpUnauthorizedError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/hogwarts/o?alt=json&name=results%2Fbeam-temp-outputs-acb95dc89b0511eb9507185e0fbdf17c%2Fc5994362-a8ca-45cc-a375-85fafb619329.outputs&uploadType=resumable>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ABg5-UzsW55q9DUiXsssbR3c0I_X85oFxjAo-FFn_ZeZ3HtZdlWPXjcd1-euaquMiOw4znDrIl8qYkBeIOBUhUlBibI', 'date': 'Sun, 11 Apr 2021 20:37:04 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'expires': 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-length': '600', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'alt-svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'status': '401'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to hogwarts/results/beam-temp-outputs-acb95dc89b0511eb9507185e0fbdf17c/c5994362-a8ca-45cc-a375-85fafb619329.outputs.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to hogwarts/results/beam-temp-outputs-acb95dc89b0511eb9507185e0fbdf17c/c5994362-a8ca-45cc-a375-85fafb619329.outputs.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get this error when I try to run this code in google cloud sdk:-

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \ --region $REGION \ --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \ --output gs://hogwarts/results/outputs \--runner DataflowRunner \ --project MyProject1 \ --temp_location gs://hogwarts/tmp/
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this issue. I have already provided the required access & I also updated my GOOGLE APPLICATION CREDENTIALS with respective keys.

Comment: Based from the error, you do not the permission to create objects in bucket `gs://hogwarts/results/`. If you are the owner of the bucket, double check the permissions. If not, ask for the bucket owner to grant you `storage.objects.create` permission.

Answer (score 0):

On local machine you need to run the command to set default application credentials, which are not set in your case. Most likely you're logged in with your own account, but application do not use it. This command you need to run in addition:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

More about this at [Set up Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)

Answer (score -1):

You need to grant the `storage.objects.create` on the `gs://hogwarts` to the compute service account. You can find this in the IAM section in GCP console.

The compute account looks like this: `xxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, where `xxxxxxx` is your project number.

Comment: This doesn't help. Error is still the same even after adding Storage Object Admin role to the mentioned Service Account.